# How do I use jsp form element contents (base64, text) as my html image src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, base64

The jsp form contents are already formatted as such:

```
<form id="textpage"
<textarea name="textbox" id="text">
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAABkCAYAAABwx8J9AAAcC0lEQVR4nO3dd1SUZ.....
</textarea></form>
```

I want to click a button on **another** html page

```
<button>Load Image!!</button>
```

and replace an existing image placeholder **src="putImageHere.png"** with

```
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAABkCAYAAABwx8J9AAAcC0lEQVR4nO3dd1SUZ..."
```

ALSO !!! The src above must be a variable as it will be different each time its loaded so it cant be hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I ended up loading an element with jquery and in the end it was as simple as

```
$('#elementId').load(URL,data,function(){
    $('#myImage').attr("src", $('#elementId').innerHTML);
});
```